# Generate Thumbnails

Tags: php

I have a php script which uploads multiple files.

What I'm Looking for is a script which generates thumbnails and keeps the ratio, so if the original is 1000 x 500 and I set width to 200 the img will be 200 x 100.

I have a variable `$file_name` which contains the file name.

The image can be jpg, png, JPEG, gif, and more types. The output file isn't important (as long as it is an image). The image can be up to 4.5 MB. I want it to give a width of 300px and height must be ratio.

Is there a easy way to create a script?

I have found https://www.php.net/imagejpeg which looks simple. But what is the easiest option. I **don't need a framework** which I can reuse, I need the simplest script. So the **smallest possible**.

Comment: Look into [GDLib](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have GD library installed, try this one:
[from magicbook](http://www.phpmagicbook.com/upload-image-and-create-thumbnail/)

Comment: that is a framework, right?

Comment: no, just easy standalone script!

Comment: // the new thumbnail image will be placed in images/thumbs/ folder $thumb_name='images/thumbs/thumb_'.$image_name; // call the function that will create the thumbnail. The function will get as parameters //the image name, the thumbnail name and the width and height desired for the thumbnail $thumb=make_thumb($newname,$thumb_name,WIDTH,HEIGHT);        make_thumb() is the part where it's all about and i gues it wont work without hte GD Library (framework) or does it work without installing hte library?

Answer (score -1):

you might find some useful scripts here.. http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/class/11.html , they are simple classes so you can also look at the code and learn how its done... HTH.